# Owl Carousel 2 set an autoplay delay

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have multiple owl carousels (version 2) on one page and want to delay the autoplay of one of them. Here is the code I am working with.

```
owldelay.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    mouseDrag: false,
    startPosition: 1,
    center: true
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In owl carousel 2 you can trigger `stop.owl.autoplay` and`play.owl.autoplay` events. 
[owl.carousel.js API events document](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

```
var $owl = $(element).owlCarousel(options);
var autoplayDelay = 2000;

if (autoplayDelay) {
   $owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
   setTimeout(function() {
    $owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
   }, autoplayDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Initialize each carousel as a stand-alone initialization

```
 $("#owl-1").owlCarousel({options});
 $("#owl-2").owlCarousel({options});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. owldelay is a variable I am using for this particular initialization. What would the option be to add the delay?

Comment: Make the autoPlay attribute false. Then use setTimeout function and set the attribute to true

Comment: That's exactly what I'm struggling with.